# EF7 beta5: Foreign Key returns null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an API using ASP.NET5 and Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta 5.

I have the Model, DbContext and the Repository created, and when I try to retrieve data from my database I get all the data, except the foreign key data.

The foreign key value is always null.

**DbContext**

```
public class MrBellhopContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyStatus> CompanyStatus { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Table("Company");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Key(c => c.CompanyId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Index(c => c.Name);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Reference(c => c.Status).InverseReference().ForeignKey<CompanyStatus>(c => c.StatusId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyStatus>().Table("CompanyStatus");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyStatus>().Key(c => c.StatusId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public class Company
{

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public CompanyStatus Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

}
```

**Repository** (only get all method)

```
    public IEnumerable<Company> GetAll()
    {
        return _dbcontext.Company.ToList();
    }
```

Retrieving data using HTTP GET I get all the data, but the value of the foreign key is null:

**JSON Response:**

```
0:  {
CompanyId: 1
Name: "Hotel Amura"
Email: "info@hotelamura.com"
Status: null
CreatedAt: "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
UpdatedAt: "2015-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

**Does anyone know how to get the Foreign Key table data using EF7 query?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lazy loading isn't implemented yet in EF7. Use the following query to eagerly-load the related entities instead.

```
_dbcontext.Company.Include(c => c.Status).ToList();
```

Comment: .Include() does not appear as function. It was my first option at the beginning, but does not exist.

Comment: `using Microsoft.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Thank. I use EF Core 2.1 and my problem has been resolved.