# EF7 beta5: Error trying to insert child entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an API using ASP.NET5 and Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta 5.

I have the Model, DbContext and the Repository created as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256142/ef7-beta5-foreign-key-returns-null-value), and when I try to insert data with a child entity my app throw an exception:

*"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Status', table 'Company'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."*

[image: Code + Exception]

The Status attribute is not null in my Company entity, but I don't know why EF is not capable of insert the value of the child entity. (in this case, "1")

This is the stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(RelationalTransaction transaction, IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper, DbContext context, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Update.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.RelationalDataStore.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at **.Data.Repositories.CompanyRepository.Create(Company company) in D:\**.Data\Repositories\CompanyRepository.cs:line 36
   at **.API.Controllers.CompanyController.Create(Company company) in D:\**.API\Controllers\CompanyController.cs:line 48
```

Here is the code:

**DbContext**

```
public class MrBellhopContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CompanyStatus> CompanyStatus { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Table("Company");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Key(c => c.CompanyId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Index(c => c.Name);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Reference(c => c.Status).InverseReference().ForeignKey<CompanyStatus>(cs => cs.StatusId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyStatus>().Table("CompanyStatus");
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyStatus>().Key(cs => cs.StatusId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
public class Company
{

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public CompanyStatus Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

}

public class CompanyStatus
{

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

**Repository** (only create method)

```
    public int Create(Company company)
    {
        _dbcontext.Add(company);
        _dbcontext.SaveChanges();

        return company.CompanyId;
    }
```

**Does anyone know how to insert correctly child entities?**

Comment: Was the database created by EF?

Comment: No, it was created via SQL statement, Table and Foreign key

Comment: Your `ForeignKey<CompanyStatus>(c => c.StatusId)` mapping doesn't look right. Try to remove it.

Comment: I have removed and it cause another exceptions in GetAll or GetOne function. I have changed by ForeignKey<CompanyStatus>(cs => cs.StatusId) to have different identifier. It still throwing exception

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Repository method to :

```
public int Create(Company company)
{
    using (MyDbcontextdbcontext context = new MyDbcontext()) 
    { 
        context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Added; 
        context.SaveChanges(); 
    }
}
```

More information : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: I get the same Exception

Comment: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Status', table 'Company'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."  -  can you just assign some value to this Status property ?

Comment: With company.Status = new CompanyStatus { StatusId = 1, Name = "Active" }; before Insert, I get the same Exception also...

Comment: What if firstly add related CompanyStatus entity to DB and only then - add your Company entity ?

Comment: The values of CompanyStatus are already in my DB. EF does not have to insert anything in the child entity table.

Answer (score 0):

The model configuration is incorrect. This is attempting to configure the foreign key for `Company` by pointing to a property on `CompanyStatus`. Foreign Keys must be a property on `Company`.

Also, `InverseReference()` is for one-to-one relationships. It appears this is trying to get a one-to-many, so use `InverseCollection()` instead.

#### Two solutions

(This assumes the schema is correctly setup to use foreign keys).

1. Add a CLR property to `Company` that contains StatusId. The configuration line should be changed to

`modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .Reference(c => c.Status)
    .InverseCollection()
    .ForeignKey(cs => cs.StatusId);`

2. If you don't want StatusId in the CLR type, then configure a shadow state property.

`modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(b=>{
        b.Property<int>("StatusId"); //this configures the shadow property
        b.Reference(c => c.Status).InverseCollection().ForeignKey("StatusId");
    });`

Comment: If I add a CLR property to Company, and configure the FK using this new property, I get an Exception: The type 'int' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TRelatedEntity' in the generic type or method 'EntityTypeBuilder<Company>

In your code there are any reference to CompanyStatus entity, It is not necessary? PS.: I have added my CompanyStatus model code above...I think that is a one-to-one reference.

Comment: If you want one-to-one, why not just put the status in the same table (entity) rather than using a FK?

Comment: By design, Status is a Entity in my model. And as such it have some other information and behaviors attached. Anyway, this is not the question.

Answer (score 0):

In EF7, you need to have your child object attached into the context. This is different from EF6, and I'm pretty sure is the scenario you are facing. Try to attach the object to the dbcontext before saving.

happened to me, check out this Issue : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2387 for more information.