# EF sometimes returns null on foreign key types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI controller that needs to return a collection from the database but I also need to remove some properties from some of the entities. However, for some reason the properties representing another entity returns null except for *sometimes* when I am stepping over the code in debug mode. I have shown the json response below which shows Sport, HomeTeam and AwayTeam as null:

[image]

But when I step over the code in debug mode I get the expected result:

[image]

The relevant controller method is as follows

```
public dynamic Get()
{
    var allPicks = _db.Picks;
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var picks = _db.UnlockedPicks
            .Include(p => p.SelectedPick.AwayTeam)
            .Include(p => p.SelectedPick.HomeTeam)
            .Include(p => p.SelectedPick.Sport)
            .Where(p => p.UserId == userId);

        var unlockedPicks = picks.Select(p => p.SelectedPick);
        var otherPicks = allPicks.Except(unlockedPicks).Select(p => new
        {
            Analysis = "",
            PickSummary = "",
            Title = p.Title,
            Id = p.Id,
            Sport = p.Sport,
            HomeTeam = p.HomeTeam,
            AwayTeam = p.AwayTeam,
            MatchTime = p.MatchTime,
            PublishTime = p.PublishTime
        });
        return new
        {
            UnlockedPicks = unlockedPicks.OrderByDescending(p => p.MatchTime),
            OtherPicks = otherPicks.OrderByDescending(p => p.MatchTime)
        };
    }
    var publicPicks = allPicks.OrderByDescending(p => p.MatchTime).Select(p => new
    {
        Analysis = "",
        PickSummary = "",
        Title = p.Title,
        Id = p.Id,
        Sport = p.Sport,
        HomeTeam = p.HomeTeam,
        AwayTeam = p.AwayTeam,
        MatchTime = p.MatchTime,
        PublishTime = p.PublishTime
    });
    return new { UnlockedPicks = new Pick[0], OtherPicks = publicPicks };
}
```

Without the `Include()` it returned null every time but how can I make it return the expected result every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are not using lazy loading. When lazy loading is deactivated, you have to call `Include` in order to load the navigation properties. If you want load all navigation properties, without calling `Include`, will have to activate the lazy loading, which can be done through the context's constructor. Like this:

```
public partial class SchoolDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public SchoolDBEntities(): base("name=SchoolDBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

The lazy loading should be activated by default. You probably have deactivated it somewhere else in your code. It is also called automatically every time you inspect a navigation property in debug mode.

Comment: I tried that but then I get `Error getting value from 'AwayTeam' on 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Pick_300C9B9073E6C214AE564BA2A5A64098700CFA4A782832A5CEC6BD386AB3AA63'.`

Comment: This class has some properties that couldn't be converted to JSON. You should never return the entire object. Instead, you should create a view model instance of your object, and then serialize it to json. Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668617/json-net-error-getting-value-from-scopeid-on-system-net-ipaddress

Comment: I ended up working around this by just storing the Id of unlocked picks and using that to get the list of picks to return

Comment: There is no `Configuration` property in `EF Core`.
I used `this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;` in `EF Core` but did not work.
But this was done to me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31256921/6778726